# NSView draw priority strange bug

Tags: cocoa, drawing, nsview

I have NSTableView for displaying some information and sometimes i need to show additional information in my custom view above NSTableView, but when I'm scrolling table MyCustomView draws above NSTableView(good!) and NSScroller draws above MyCustomView(bad...) despite the fact that MyCustomView higher than NSScroller in object tree. I get result displayed on the right image. How i can reach result like on the left image?

[image]

Comment: AFAIK views cannot overlap in Cocoa so the behavior you get is inherent to the way the framework is designed. Another option would be to use an NSPopover for your additional info.

Comment: But is there a way to make full custom NSPopover drawing to make it like simple view? I don't want to get box with triangle.

Comment: No. The popover exists outside the view hierarchy to which it is attached. Internally it is probably a customized window frame. I think you need to reconsider your design.

Comment: @Roger Oh, is there a way to draw vertical scroller on the left side of NSScrollView?

Comment: Not in the standard NSScrollView. You probably would have to implement your own scroll view or subclass NSScrollView and see if you can move the scrollbar to the other side. Personally I would not do that as it violates OS X UI design protocol. And you still could end up with unexpected behaviour as NSView are designed not to overlap.